# HTML Css Position Absolute Not Working

Tags: html, css

How do I keep these buttons exactly on the boxes from the background images? When you resize the window/browser then their positions/sizes change and they no longer fit inside the background image boxes.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.Div1 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/7NQ3IOt.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 76.1vw;
}

.Div2 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/CjVMSqG.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 169vw;
}

.Btns {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    left: 17.4vw;
    width: 26.3vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Div1">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4.8vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Div2">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the measurements and the default padding, border, and browser specific styling for the buttons. I edited the fiddle  with calculated values with some manual tweaking:

For short, the padding should also be in `vw` units, and set `-webkit-appearance:  none;`.

You can see a CodePen here:

https://codepen.io/elujambio/pen/EQQOgK

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.Div1 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/7NQ3IOt.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 76.1vw;
}

.Div2 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/CjVMSqG.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 169vw;
}

.Btns {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    box-sizing:  border-box; 
    padding:  .25vw 0; 
    left: 18vw;
    width: 26.75vw; 
    -webkit-appearance:  none;  
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Div1">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4.8vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Div2">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```